# Do I need to synchronize reads on elements in std::sort called with std::execution::par?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, language-lawyer, c++17

If I have the following code that makes use of execution policies, do I need to synchronize all accesses to `Foo::value` even when I'm just reading the variable?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
struct Foo { int value; int getValue() const { return value; } };

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    //fill foos here...
    std::sort(std::execution::par, foos.begin(), foos.end(), [](const Foo & left, const Foo & right)
    {
        return left.getValue() > right.getValue();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

My concern is that `std::sort()` will move (or copy) elements asynchronously which is effectively equivalent to asynchronously writing to `Foo::value` and, therefore, all read and write operations on that variable need to be synchronized. Is this correct or does the sort function itself take care of this for me?

What if I were to use `std::execution::par_unseq`?

Comment: It would be rather pointless to synchronise *just reads*, now wouldn't it? If you need to synchronise at all, you need to synchronise reads *and* writes (or just writes). But you don't have any opportunity to synchronise writes. Ergo...?

Comment: @n.m. I do have the opportunity to synchronize writes by overloading the assignment operator of `Foo` and work with locks etc in there.

Comment: So if parallel sort were defined this way, you wouldn't be able to sort any data you don't own the definition of. Certainly not any built-in types. Wouldn't that be rather limiting? Not to say outrageously stupid?

Comment: @nm Yes, my sentiments exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow [the rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#user-1), i.e. you don't modify anything or rely on the identity of the objects being sorted inside your callback, then you're safe.

The parallel algorithm is responsible for synchronizing access to the objects it modifies.
See [[algorithms.parallel.exec]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-2):

> If an object is modified by an element access function, the algorithm will perform no other unsynchronized accesses to that object. The modifying element access functions are those which are specified as modifying the object. [ *Note*: For example, `swap()`, `++`, `--`, `@=`, and assignments modify the object. For the assignment and `@=` operators, only the left argument is modified. — *end note* ]

In case of `std::execution::par_unseq`, there's the additional requirement on the user-provided callback that it isn't allowed to call *[vectorization-unsafe](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-6)* functions, so you can't even lock anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is OK.  After all, you have told `std::sort` what you want of it and you would expect it to behave sensibly as a result, given that it is presented with all the relevant information up front.  There's not a lot of point to the execution policy parameter at all, otherwise.

Where there might be an issue (although not in your code, as written) is if the comparison function has side effects.  Suppose we innocently wrote this:

```
int numCompares;
std::sort(std::execution::par, foos.begin(), foos.end(), [](const Foo & left, const Foo & right)
{
    ++numCompares;
    return left.getValue() > right.getValue();
});
```

Now we have introduced a race condition, since two threads of execution might be passing through that code at the same time and access to numCompares is not synchronised (or, as I would put it, serialised).

But, in my slightly contrived example, we don't need to be so naive, because we can simply say:

```
std::atomic_int numCompares;
```

and then the problem goes away (and this particular example would also work with what appears to me to be the spectacularly useless `std::execution::par_unseq`, because `std_atomic_int` is lockless on any sensible platform, thank you Rusty).

So, in summary, don't be too concerned about what `std::sort` does (although I would certainly knock up a quick test program and hammer it a bit to see if it does actually work as I am claiming).  Instead, be concerned about what *you* do.

More [here](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/parallel-algorithm-of-the-standard-template-library).

---

**Edit** And while Rusty was digging that up, I did in fact write that quick test program (had to fix your lambda) and, sure enough, it works fine.  I can't find an online compiler that supports `execution` (MSVC seems to think it is experimental) so I can't offer you a live demo, but when run on the latest version of MSVC, this code:

```
#define _SILENCE_PARALLEL_ALGORITHMS_EXPERIMENTAL_WARNING
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int num_foos = 100000;

struct Foo
{
    Foo (int value) : value (value) { }
    int value;
    int getValue() const { return value; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.reserve (num_foos);

    // fill foos
    for (int i = 0; i < num_foos; ++i)
         foos.emplace_back (rand ());

    std::sort (std::execution::par, foos.begin(), foos.end(), [](const Foo & left, const Foo & right)
    {
        return left.getValue() < right.getValue();
    });

    int last_foo = 0;
    for (auto foo : foos)
    {
        if (foo.getValue () < last_foo)
        {
            std::cout << "NOT sorted\n";
            break;
        }

        last_foo = foo.getValue ();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Generates the following output every time I run it:

```
<nothing>
```

QED.

Comment: Yes I've got the same results when running your test. Thanks!

Comment: OK, good, thanks.  It's always nice to be sure, threads are slippery things.